# How to get user input for a struct using other function to get the user input in C99

Tags: c, struct

I am getting an error because I need to put a return value for this struct.

```
struct Item enterItem(int sku)
{
        char name;

        printf("        SKU: %d", sku);
        printf("       Name: "); scanf("%20[^\n]", &name);
        clearKeyboard();                     // Function call to remove'\n'
        printf("      Price: ");
        getDouble();                         // Function call to get user input in double
        printf("   Quantity: ");
        getInt();                            // Function call to get user input in int
        printf("Minimum Qty: ");
        getInt();
        printf("   Is taxed: ");
        getYesOrNo();                        // Function call to get user input in bool > (Y)es or (N)o

}
```

Comment: Please post a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Where are you storeing the value read? Also `char name; scanf("%20[^\n]", &name);` is bad because you will be allowed to enter only zero-character string (plus terminating null character).

Comment: You generally shouldn't pass/return structures by value. You should pass pointers to them to avoid copying.

Comment: So why don't you return a struct since you know you need to? Declare a local variable of that struct type, fill it in as required and return it. Or better still, modify the function to accept a pointer to a struct that the caller provides.

Answer (score 0):

You should create a struture object (data) to return and return it.

What you want may be like this:

```
struct Item
{
        char name[21];
        double price;
        int quantity;
        int minimum_qty;
        _Bool is_taxed;
};

struct Item enterItem(int sku)
{
        struct Item item;

        printf("        SKU: %d", sku);
        printf("       Name: "); scanf("%20[^\n]", item.name);
        clearKeyboard();                     // Function call to remove'\n'
        printf("      Price: ");
        item.price = getDouble();            // Function call to get user input in double
        printf("   Quantity: ");
        item.quantity = getInt();            // Function call to get user input in int
        printf("Minimum Qty: ");
        item.minimum_qty = getInt();
        printf("   Is taxed: ");
        item.is_taxed = getYesOrNo();        // Function call to get user input in bool > (Y)es or (N)o

        return item;    
}
```